# How to create a button that will go to a razor page when clicked ("Razor page" in dotnet core 2)

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

I can use an anchor tag helper to go to a different razor page (from an existing razor page) e.g. this works:

```
<a asp-page="./EditReport" asp-route-id="@report.IntegrityReportId" class="btn fa fa-edit"></a>
```

How can I get a similar thing to work but using a button. I have tried:

```
<button type="button" asp-route-data="@report.IntegrityReportId" asp-route="EditReport">EditReport</button>
```

But the page never loads. I also tried using the page handler with different variations of:

```
<input type="button" asp-page-handler="EditReport" asp-route="@report.IntegrityReportId"/>
```

and associated (in the page cs file):

```
public ActionResult OnEditReport(int id)
        {
            return RedirectToPage("./EditReport", id);
        }
```

but this method never gets called (I've also tried naming method OnPostEditReport but same problem.

If it helps, my original NON- dotnet core app worked fine with:

```
<button type="button" title="Edit report" class="btn btn-datatable fa fa-edit" onclick="location.href = '@Url.Action("EditReport", "Home", new {id = report.IntegrityReportID})'"></button>
```

Any help is appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I managed to get the effect I needed by using the below anchor - so it looks like a button..

```
<a asp-page="./EditReport" asp-route-id="@report.IntegrityReportId" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can not use just a button which will redirect to an other razor page without javascript. You can use a submit button inside a form tag in order to redirect to an other razor page. The following example demonstrates how to make a GET redirect which will redirect to the About page:

```
<form method="get">
    <button type="submit" asp-page="./About">Click me to go to the About page</button>
</form>
```

if you want a POST request use the following code:

```
<form method="post">
    <button type="submit" asp-page="./About">Click me to go to the About page</button>
</form>
```

In both cases you can define routing values or handlers in order to cover the requirements.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks pitaridis but I still can't get this to work. the page does look like it's doing something but then the original page just shows up again. How would you do it in javascript? Do you know why we need to do this in javascript and/or why this is different to standard MVC where I could just use formaction? Many thanks

Answer (score 4):

The solution below worked for me in my ASP.NET Core 3.1 project:

`<a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" asp-page="./Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id"><i class="fas fa-user"></i> Edit</a>`

The highlighted code above is all on one line, just the way stack overflow is presenting the answer. Note I chose to display the icon before the text in the button, then I added a single chazr space before the button label 'Edit' just so the button looks a little nicer.

Answer (score 0):

I know its a year late, but you have to remove 'type="button"', also try removing '.' from asp-page="./EditReport".
BR.

Answer (score 0):

This works in ASPNET Core 3.1.

```
<form method="get" action="/myRazorPage">
    <button type="submit">Join Now</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

using button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn" onclick="window.location.href = '/YourPage'">Button Title</button>
```